# Port Forwarding with OpenVPN active on DD-WRT

Tags: router, port-forwarding, openvpn, dd-wrt

At home, I have two networks, my home network, then a second network separated by a DD-WRT router, which I call my homework network.

This homework network can be treated as a separate network to my home network, as the router I am using is connected to the home network through the WAN port, and runs OpenVPN to connect to my work network.

While this is useful (as my entire homework computer's startup proceedure from blackscreen to desktop is done on the companies network), it prevents me from accessing that box while anywhere in the house when connected to the home (wireless) network.

I use SSH (via Putty) to remotely access my boxs, and do the same to access my homework computer. However, when I forward port 22 on the DD-WRT router to my homework computer, I can only access it when the VPN connection is offline.

Is there a way that I can have the router constantly connected to the VPN, but to allow for incoming requests from the "WAN" to be forwarded correctly?